# Filter ItemsSource

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, itemssource

With this code I'm setting the ItemsSource of my datagrid. However I've got more wpf controls that are needed to filter the datagrid, for example from a time range. I could write a new query for this but that seems unnecessary as the data is already available, I just need to filter it. What's the best way to do this?

Any help I could get would be really appreciated!

```cs
DateTime dateStart = CalenderSearch.SelectedDates.First();
DateTime dateEnd = CalenderSearch.SelectedDates.Last();

ObjectQuery<Fouten> fouten = eventsEntities.Foutens;

var query =
    (from fout in fouten
    where dateStart <= fout.Datum && dateEnd >= fout.Datum && fout.Rapporten.Treinen.NameTrein == trein.NameTrein
    orderby fout.Datum, fout.Time
    select new
    {
        Datum = fout.Datum,
        Time = fout.Time,
        FoutCode = fout.FoutCode,
        Omschrijving = fout.Omschrijving,
        Teller = fout.Teller,
        Module = fout.Module,
        FoutId = fout.FoutId

    }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Fouten
    {
        Datum = x.Datum,
        Time = x.Time,
        FoutCode = x.FoutCode,
        Omschrijving = x.Omschrijving,
        Teller = x.Teller,
        Module = x.Module,
        FoutId = x.FoutId
    }).ToList();

if (query.Count == 0)
    foutensDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
else
    foutensDataGrid.ItemsSource = query;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF, each collection that are used as an `ItemsSource` in a GUI element have an [`ICollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) associated with it.
`ICollectionView` has a [`Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, which is of type `Predicate<object>`.

If you set this `Filter` and call [`Refresh()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) afterwards, the DataGrid will update itself to only show the items where `Filter` returned true.

An example how you could use this:

```
var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(foutensDataGrid.ItemsSource);
collectionView.Filter = o => {
    var fouten = o as Fouten;
    //do your filtering, e.g.
    return fouten.Datum <= dateEnd && fouten.Datum >= dateStart;
}
collectionView.Refresh();
```

Comment: Is there a difference in performance with what Vadim answered? or are both options equal?

Comment: @Goostrabha I'm not really sure. It could be, since with this solution you are only setting the filter, so WPF can figure out the elements which are filtered out and only remove the GUI elements for these. With his solution, he is completely resetting the ItemsSource, so the DataGrid will have to re-render all elements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, both of you!

Comment: @Goostrabha
First of all in the performance context you should not have extra iteration of your collection via `select new {...}` , `.AsEnumerable()` and `Select(...)`, just call `ToList()` immediately after LINQ query. 
Also, it's hard to compare this solutions. In `Filter` you need to cast each value from `object` to `Fouten` and then WPF will cast it back. But it can be bit faster because WPF can evaluate already rendered content. 
Then, short answer - nobody knows :) Bit longer - nobody cares because it's not the slowest part of the app.

Comment: The issue with when i did a Tolist() instant was that i get the error Error 22 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HerstelmanagerV3.Fouten>' C:\Users\twa0003\Desktop\HerstelmanagerV3\HerstelmanagerV3\MainWindow.xaml.cs 485 20 HerstelmanagerV3 And this was a solution i found on here for this issue

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You can save loaded data in class field and then filter it via handle buttonClicks:

```
public class YourView
{
    private List<Fouten> loadedData;
    public void LoadData(...)
    {
        ObjectQuery<Fouten> fouten = eventsEntities.Foutens;

        // here you save unfiltered data to the field and then you can use it to filter collection
        loadedData = ...;

        // if you want to filter values immediately you can call filter method right here
        // FilterByFoutCode(someValue);

        if (loadedData.Count == 0)
            foutensDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
        else
            foutensDataGrid.ItemsSource = loadedData;
    }

    private void FilterByFoutCodeButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var filter = FoutCodeTextBox.Content.ToString();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        {
            // if your filter is not empty then filter loadedData by criteria 
            FilterByFoutCode(filter);
        }
    }

    private void FilterByFoutCode(string filter)
    {
        foutensDataGrid.ItemsSource = loadedData.Where(x => x.FoutCode == filter);
    }
}
```

Also,  in the performance context you should not have extra iteration of your collection via `select new {...}` , `.AsEnumerable()` and `Select(...)`, just call `ToList()` immediately after LINQ query.

Finally [MVVM pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) is a standard de-facto for WPF it can be useful for your app.