# Hide rows in DataGrid where multiple conditions are met, in an MVVM context

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to hide all the rows in a `DataGrid` where two conditions are met:

- the `ViewModel` has `bool ShowSelectedCat { get; }` set to true
- `Cat.equals(ViewModel.SelectedCat)` where `Cat` is a string specific to a row

  ```
                      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category">
                          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:LocalImage}">
                                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cat}"/>
                              </DataTemplate>
                          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  ```

I would like also to respect the MVVM pattern. `ShowSelectedCat` is changed by  an `ICommand` and will invoke a `PropertyChangedEventHandler`.

I could not see how to use `DataGrid.RowStyle` for those multiple conditions.

Comment: Have a look at [multidatatrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.multidatatrigger?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Sound good at first glance, however there is one tricky condition : `<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedCategory [datacontext is ViewModel] }" Value="{Binding Category [datacontext is LocalImage (of the row)]}}" />` and Value can only bind to a `DependencyProperty`

Comment: You can check the accepted answer of this question. It may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839104/datagrid-rowstyle-binding-value-in-datatrigger

Comment: Are you trying to [Filter itemsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765918/filter-itemsource). This can be easily handled in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first condition is easy:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding DataContex.ShowSelectedCat, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Value="True" />
```

The second can't be expressed in XAML. You could use a converter and a `<MultiBinding>` that binds to both `ViewModel.SelectedCat` and `Cat` and compare them:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.ShowSelectedCat, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Value="True" />
        <Condition Value="True">
            <Condition.Binding>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <local:MultiConverter />
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.SelectedCat" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                    <Binding Path="Cat" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Condition.Binding>
        </Condition>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter ... />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

---

```
public class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        values[0]?.Equals(values[1]);

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: Sounds excellent, however `<Binding Path="Cat" />` will have the datacontext set to ViewModel and will complain; Cat is a property of LocalImage, which is used by each row.

Comment: The `DataContext` of a `DataGridRow` is the current object in the `ItemsSource`, i.e. a `LocalImage` in your case. That's why this binding has no `Source` specified.

Comment: Congratulations ! It was not obvious at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
                            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding _prop1}" Value="value1">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding _prop2}" Value="value2">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: This won't work: I need `DoCollapse = A&B`, not `DoCollapse = A|B` (your logic), furthermore value1 and value2 are changing (properties)

Comment: do you see the difference between AND and OR ?